# Accidentally over-wrote named.conf

Tags: centos, bind

I've accidentally overwritten my `named.conf`.  I haven't restarted named, yet.

Is it possible to get a complete copy of all the zones that it is currently serving so that I can replace the configuration file?

Comment: Just restore from backup.

Comment: Don't you have the corresponding settings on your DNS slave?

Comment: Backups. BACKUPS!

Answer (score 1):

You can do an AXFR with `dig @localhost example.com axfr` to get the contents of a specific zone (assuming that you've allowed AXFR transfers), but I don't think that there's a way to list the configured zones. You should probably be using [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) and be making backups for situations like this though ;-)